# Declare types on destructured lambda arguments?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

vscode puts a wavy line under the following construct:

```
const Group = ({messages, me, people}) => {
    return <div>{ just a small React JSX component using an ES6 arrow function }</div>
}
```

Because the types can't be specified AFAIK in destructuring, they take the type any, so vscode marks the line with a red underline, and marks the file name in red too. I like to use that as feedback as to what needs to be done next, but it's throwing me off.

Is there a similar, almost as nice way to structure the code where the IDE won't complain? Alternately is there a way to tell vscode to ignore it?

Ironically the linter is extremely strict and catches any extra or missing space (I need to dial that down, that drives me crazy) but is silent about this line!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the type for the whole argument, which means you need to restate the member names unfortunately:

```
const Group = ({messages, me, people} : {messages: string, me: string, people: string}) => {
    return <div></div>
}
```

Comment: That's pretty good actually. A little DRY, but I don't think that can be helped here.

Comment: @Eloff don't forget to mark as answered if it solved the problem